# Error creating .eps output with matplotlib with LaTex text rendering (usetex)

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector-graphics

I was trying to create .eps output with Latex text rendering using the example provided by the [matplotlib homepage](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
This demo is tex_demo.py modified to have unicode. See that file for
more information.
"""
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex']=True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.unicode']=True
from numpy import arange, cos, pi
from matplotlib.pyplot import (figure, axes, plot, xlabel, ylabel, title,
     grid, savefig, show)

figure(1, figsize=(6,4))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.7])
t = arange(0.0, 1.0+0.01, 0.01)
s = cos(2*2*pi*t)+2
plot(t, s)

xlabel(r'\textbf{time (s)}')
ylabel(r'\textit{Velocity (\u00B0/sec)}', fontsize=16)
title(r"\TeX\ is Number $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-e^{i\pi}}{2^n}$!",
      fontsize=16, color='r')
grid(True)
savefig('tex_demo.eps')
```

Where I just added the "*savefig('tex_demo.eps')*" command at the end. However, I get the error message:

> File "", line 1, in 
>   runfile('E:/Software/Python/Test/Plot/Matplotlib/tex_unicode_demo.py',
>   wdir='E:/Software/Python/Test/Plot/Matplotlib')
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 540, in runfile   execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "E:/Software/Python/Test/Plot/Matplotlib/tex_unicode_demo.py",
>   line 27, in    savefig('tex_demo.eps',format='eps')
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 577,
>   in savefig   res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1470,
>   in savefig   self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py",
>   line 161, in print_figure   FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args,
>   **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line
>   2194, in print_figure   **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py",
>   line 992, in print_eps   return self._print_ps(outfile, 'eps', *args,
>   **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py",
>   line 1016, in _print_ps   **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py",
>   line 1381, in _print_figure_tex   rotated=psfrag_rotated)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py",
>   line 1539, in gs_distill   your image.\nHere is the full report
>   generated by ghostscript:\n\n' + fh.read())
>
> RuntimeError: ghostscript was not able to process     your image. Here
>   is the full report generated by ghostscript:

I already made sure that the pathes to the executeables of LaTeX, dvipng and Ghostscript are in my path variable.

Matplotlib: 1.4.2

Ghostscript: 9.15

Python: 2.7.6

OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: eps does not do unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't managed to directly solve your problem. However I have found a work around. I have an install of `Cygwin` on my windows PC. Before I call my python script I added the `Cygwin` bin directory into my windows path:

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin64\bin"
```

For me at least this solved my problem. Hope it is of help.